# Allow users to only open file but not save them

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to make user open a file on network BUT DON'T ALLOW them to save it?

When I `<a href="file:///filename.doc">Filenmae</a>`, i get options to `Save` or `Open` a file. I don't want users to save that file, they can only OPEN them and read/edit them.

Regards

Comment: Not possible.  Anything they see can somehow be saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is handled by the web browser, not by code.  In this case they're hitting the file system directly rather than a web server (so there's no place to override headers or anything like that) and the browser is acting accordingly.  I'm thinking the only way to achieve what you seek is to configure the browser to always open the file in the associated program rather than prompt the user.  If you're talking about a lot of web browsers, that could be a pain.

Also, since it's opening the file from the user's local file system, they can still save it.  Once it's open in the associated program (in this case I'm assuming MS Word), they can save it from there.  The only way to "not allow" them to save it in this case would be to remove their write access to the file at the OS level (I'm assuming Windows).  This also assumes they don't have administrative rights.  Otherwise, you'll want it on a file share on a server or something where you can control access.

But even then, they can just save it locally somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, unless you also make them open some other program that hijacks the basic saving/opening functionality on their computer.